# Que ventajas me da una aplicación móvil contra una web responsiva

Tags: aplicación-web, app

Aparte de las notificaciones que otras funcionalidades nos dan las apps. Recordemos que en el mercado las aplicaciones móviles son mas costosas que los sitios web y muchos clientes exigen una explicación de dicha diferencia en coste ya que una web con bootstrap nos brinda una buena experiencia movil.

Answer (score 1):

Ademas de velocidad, si la info esta guardada en la app no se hace dependiente de internet, la experiencia del usuario siempre es mejor en una app que en una web responsive

Answer (score 1):

Va depender mucho de tus necesidades y de tus requerimientos, pero enlistaría los siguientes puntos:

- Velocidad de respuesta.
- Mayor control en eventos de usuario.
- Acceso al hardware del dispositivo(GPS, cámara, etc)
- Monetización
- Visualización de la aplicación en la tienda de aplicaciones
- Uso offline (Dependerá de tus necesidades)

**Edición:** En mi opinión considero que una aplicación nativa es más costosa por el hecho de la especialización por plataforma que se requiere.

Saludos